# How does ProcessBuilder.start() works

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am trying to understand the ProcessBuilder mechanism. Once the ProcessBuilder.start() method is invoked will it track the shell command.

Will the command waits until the command returns success or it continues with the other commands.

If ProcessBuilder does not wait until the invoked command, is there any way i can make the method wait for a flag.

Comment: Did you search Google or read the [`ProcessBuilder` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), or research your questions through trial and error?

Comment: I would like to understand how the back anf forth calls happen between the ProcessBuilder and the Process which is running. How do they communicate. I have googled and read the documentation. I found it little difficult to understand.

Comment: From what I read: A `ProcessBuilder` instance can start a new process, via `start()`, and that's as far as it goes regarding communication between the `ProcessBuilder` instance and the new process, other than error/exception handling. The `start()` method does return a `Process` though. Which you could use to monitor the new process like @BalajiKatika's answer seems to discuss.

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding from the [JavaDoc for the `ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html), it just spawns a separate process and continues with its execution.

To wait until the command is finished (success/failure), I would suggest you invoke `Process#waitFor()` on the `Process` object returned by `ProcessBuilder#start()`. You could then query for `exitValue()` etc., and take necessary actions.